# Handle an authenticated user behind an IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY path in Symfony

Tags: symfony

I have a route that allows both authenticated users and anonymous users.
(The response will be different if the user is authenticated).
But for a logged user, I'm unable to retrieve the user's token. Is there a way to handle this?
Thanks!

Here's my security.yml file:

```
firewalls:
    login:
        pattern:  ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        form_login:
            check_path:               /api/login_check
            success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
            require_previous_session: false
            username_parameter:       _email
            password_parameter:       _password

    episodes:
        pattern:   ^/api/episodes
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true

    api:
        pattern:   ^/api
        stateless: true
        lexik_jwt: ~

access_control:
    - { path: ^/api/login,    roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api/episodes, roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY] }
    - { path: ^/api,          roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Comment: Make sure the route is behind one of your configured firewalls, or otherwise you will not have access to the authenticated user.

Comment: Hey Yoshi, thank your for your answer. I've edited my post to put my security.yml file. So yes, the route is behind one of my firewalls. Do you see something wrong?

Comment: From a first glance, I'd say try to use the same [*context*](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#firewall-context) for all firewalls and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `security.authorization_checker` service to check if user is logged in. In your controller you can do that like this:

```
$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY');
```

This returns boolean value.

Refer to [Symfony Secutiry Component Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#checking-to-see-if-a-user-is-logged-in-is-authenticated-fully) for more details.

Especially take a look at the difference between `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` and `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED`, to be aware of what's going on in your application.